# Animation on add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'am trying to set animation on addclass and removeclass, but unfortunately its not working.

So thats my code:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
            $("#top").on("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").removeClass("hide4e");
                $(this).find("footer").removeClass("hide4e");
            }).on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").addClass("hide4e");
                $(this).find("footer").addClass("hide4e");
            });
        });
```

I found 2 solutions -

1. with jquery ui - not working
2. with css transions which also not working

```js
jQuery(function($) {
            $("#top").on("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").removeClass("hide4e");
                //$(this).find("footer").removeClass("hide4e");
            }).on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").addClass("hide4e");
                //$(this).find("footer").addClass("hide4e");
            });
        });
```

```css
.nav-parent {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;

}

 .hide4e {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>




<body id="top" class="album-template-default single single-album postid-51 apollo_validation_on wide wp-3_8">

    <!--iw-->

    
    <div id="iw-container">

        <div id="root">
            <div id="whole-bg-image">
                <div id="album-controls">
                    <span id="prevslide" class="arrow-left"></span>
                    <span id="play-button" class="action" data-play="Play" data-pause="Pause"></span>
                    <span id="nextslide" class="arrow-right"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="header-container" class="glass">
                <header id="header" class="glass">
                    <div class="add-ons clearfix">
                        <div class="content">

                        </div>
                    </div>





<!-- STACKOVERFLOW NEEDED START -->
                <div class="nav-parent">
                    <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                        <a id="logo" href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>index.html" title="AlexValtchev.com &#8211; Alex Valtchev Photography" rel="home"><img src="https://vimastudio.com/images/vsLogo.png" alt="AlexValtchev.com &#8211; Alex Valtchev Photography" /></a>

                        <h3 class="assistive-text">Main menu</h3>
                                                <a class="assistive-text" href="#begin-of-content" title="Skip to primary content">Skip to primary content</a>
                        <a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="Skip to secondary content">Skip to secondary content</a>

                        <div class="menu-container">
                            <div class="mobtn"></div>
       <div id="iw-header-button"><div class="img"></div></div>
                                                <ul id="menu-menuen-1" class="top-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-35"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>index.php"><span>Начало</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>about.php"><span>За нас</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>portfolio.php"><span>Портфолио</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-32"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>blog.php"><span>Блог</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>allclients.php"><span>Клиенти</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>partners.php"><span>Партньори</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; ?>contacts.php"><span>За контакти</span></a></li>
</ul>                        </div>
                    </nav><!-- #access -->
                </div>
                
                
                <!-- STACKOVERFLOW NEEDED END -->
                
                
                </header>
            </div>
            <!-- /#header-container -->
            <div id="mid" class="clearfix  full-width">

                <div class="seo-album">
                    <div class="brick">
                     
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="album-things" class="load-item">
                    <em id="prev-thumb"></em>
                    <em id="next-thumb"></em>

                    <!--Slide captions displayed here-->
                    <div class="desc-and-list">
                        <div id="slide-text">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h1 class="caption"></h1>
                                <div class="descpription"></div>
                                <span id="close-text" title="Hide description"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="text-controls" class="position-holder">
                            <span id="show-text" class="action" title="Show description"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Thumbs-->
                    <div id="other-albums"></div>
                    <div id="thumb-tray">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span id="prev-tray-thumb" class="arrow-left"></span>
                            <span id="next-tray-thumb" class="arrow-right"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Thumb Tray button-->
                    <div id="tray-button" title="Show thumbnails"></div>

                    <!--Time Bar-->
                    <div id="progress-back">
                        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="album-icons" class="album-icons">
                    <a class="info-ico" title="Show description"></a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- #mid -->
           
           
    <style>
 
 .nav-parent {
    transition: opacity 1s, height 0s 1s;
 }
        .hide4e {
            display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $("#top").on("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").removeClass("hide4e");
                $(this).find("footer").removeClass("hide4e");
            }).on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).find(".nav-parent").addClass("hide4e");
                $(this).find("footer").addClass("hide4e");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

html is mess here, but needed part is between  and

So is there any other solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: `with css transions which also not working` CSS transitions would be the best way to do this. Could you please add a full example of your HTML and CSS code to the question along with why you believe it's not working for you

Comment: I edited the first post.

Comment: You'll need to include the HTML on which the CSS and jQuery act. When you're [edit]ing the question, click on the icon that has `<>` on a page; that's Stack Snippets, which lets you write runnable examples.

Comment: Okay, I did that.

Comment: You are adding a class that hides the DOM element `display: none;` so if anything is happening to the element, is happening while is invisible...

Comment: Yes, I want to set animation on hiding.

Comment: `display: none` can’t be animated. Use something else like `position: absolute; visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Is there any other solutions for this, because position: absolute; visibility: hidden; is not hidding all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I cant animate display: none, so I used visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; to hide the elements. Thank you all!